# regex for collect letter inside string ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string

how to resolve this problem in ruby?

i have string like this :

```
a = "ABC101"
b= "JE1221"
```

how to get result like this using regex in ruby?

```
a = "ABC"
b = "JE"
```

how do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. How have you tried to solve this? We'd like to see what you tried so we can correct it, instead of writing various solutions that don't fit your code.

Comment: Are the strings "ABC101" and "JE1221" or are they `a = "ABC101"` and `b= "JE1221"`? And do you want the alpha characters, or the assignment too?

Comment: You don't need a regex. You can do this with standard string functions. See [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30113664/1301972).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
a.gsub!(/(\W|\d)/, "")
=> "ABC"

b.gsub!(/(\W|\d)/, "")
 => "JE"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`sub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-sub-21) method with an argument of `\d+`, which means one or more of any digit:

```
a.sub!(/\d+/, "")
#=> ABC
```

The `!` character in `sub!` indicates that the receiver will be modified in place.

There's also a [`gsub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) method that performs a global substitution.  For example:

```
a = "ABC101ABC101"

a.sub!(/\d+/, "")
#=> ABCABC101

a.gsub!(/\d+/, "")
#=> ABCABC
```

Comment: It is much slower to use `sub` or `gsub` to remove characters not wanted, than it is to use a pattern to select the characters you do want.

Comment: @the Tin Man. Would you suggest using `scan` instead?

Comment: Until we know the exact strings the OP has it's too early to propose any solution. Right?

Answer (score 0):

### Use [String#delete](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-delete) with Destructuring Assignment

You can map the delete method onto an array of strings and assign them both at once. For example:

```
a, b = ["ABC101", "JE1221"].map { |e| e.delete '0-9' }
# => ["ABC", "JE"]
```

This assigns each variable as expected, provided that you have the same number of variables on the left-hand side as you do values on the right.

```
a
# => "ABC"
b
# => "JE"
```